# How do I determine why all outlets on a breaker stopped working, but the hot-grounds are still 120V?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, troubleshooting

Edit: Is there a way to find an open neutral between the working breaker and the first nonworking outlet without cutting open the wall. It is a pretty straight shot between the 2 with no junction boxes or known splices between.

3 outlets on 1 breaker,  all hot-ground = 120V, neutral-hot and neutral-ground register nothing using a Sperry voltage tester ET6204. Using Ideal circuit tester 61-035, all 3 lights light up in all 3 outlets (top and bottom).
I identified which outlet is first. Breaker hot-neutral is 120V.
A window was recently replaced near the first outlet in the line. Electrical line runs barely under window in wall. Window attachment screws are in wall very near outlet.
What am I looking for and could a window screw have caused the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have an open (i.e. broken or loose/disconnected) neutral wire.

Comment: Am I looking for an actual broken neutral wire? It has to be between the breaker and the first outlet then, correct?

Comment: Broken between since you postulate screw damage, or possibly disconnected  AT the first outlet (disconnected wire from outlet, outlet used backstabs and they failed, etc.), yes. Possibly a junction box connection failed between, if there IS a junction box between.

Comment: Thanks. I rewired the outlets (was backstabs). That is actually one of the less complicated outlets. Didn't find any junction boxes between.

Comment: Worth turning the breaker off and checking that the neutral screws are tight on that outlet. Probably not the problem but quick and easy if it is.

Comment: Checked screws. Checked under outlet box where wire goes in, no issue screw doesn't enter wall that far. I guess that means the problem is somewhere in the 20 feet between that outlet and the breaker box.